# Can 'residential context' be used interchangeably with 'domestic context'?

Tags: word-usage

I know that when I am referring to a home, I can refer to it using the words - in a residential/domestic context... Is it the same for different places of stay like  hostels, old age homes, refugee camps? Can I refer to them in the same way?

For example, in the residential context of a refugee camp, we can see that... Or when  the domestic context of the refugee camp is studied, it is obvious that...

Comment: I don't think either term is appropriate in the example you give.

Comment: I think of *residential context* in relation to an *idea*, not necessarily a *place*. So you might say that *in a residential context, the notion of 'heavy' traffic is not nearly as severe as it would be in a commercial context*. But you wouldn't say that * *you are leaving your residential context early to get to work on time*; you might say instead that you are leaving your *house* or *home* early.

Answer (score 1):

"Domestic" has more "family" connotations: it refers to the family home.  For example, "Domestic violence" means "violence from one family member onto another".

"residential" simply refers to where someone lives.  "Residential" could refer to a care home, where old people live together for example.

In this sense, using "domestic" with a refugee camp is not appropriate because that camp is not a family home, even if a family happens to be living in it.

EDIT:

I also think that "residential" isn't right for a refugee camp either, as "residential" makes one think of a permanent structure, which was designed for people to live in.  A refugee camp is more temporary, or is supposed to be at least.